# How to filter a dataframe using a list of multiple ranges of a variable

Tags: r

I'm attempting to filter a large signal intensity dataframe using a list of ranges of one variable (chromosome position) in the dataframe. The list has 256 ranges in total, with start and end positions. I can successfully filter the dataframe using a single range, but I can't seem to get this to loop over the entire dataframe.

DT is the original signal intensity dataframe (SNP, Chr, Position, Intensity Ratio) and PR is a two column dataframe with start and end Position:

```
Chr   Start    End
1     130104   207101
1     1423247  4459324
1     6543121  7924836
```

This line of code works to extract the data from a single range:

```
test <- DT %>% filter(Chr %in% ("1")) %>% filter(Position %in% c(PR$Start[1]:PR$End[1]))
```

This does NOT work:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(PR)){
    help <- DT %>% filter(Chr %in% ("1")) %>% filter(Position %in% c(PR$Start[i]:PR$End[i]))
  }
```

The above code produces a dataframe with a random selection of data that doesn't correspond to the range of positions.

This doesn't work either:

```
range = data.table(start=PR$Start,end=PR$End)
x <- DT[Position %inrange% range]
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Looks like you need a rolling join/nonequi join.  Can you show `PR`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. PR looks like this: ```Chr   Start    End
1     130104   207101
1     1423247  4459324
1     6543121  7924836```

Comment: please update it in your post by `edit`ing the post so that others would be able to check more easily

Comment: I think I do need a rolling nonequi join, thanks for this advice. Now to figure out how to do that!

Answer (score 0):

Your `data.table` solution worked for me. Does this work for you, with my made up data?

```
dt <- data.table(id = 1:100, var=runif(100))
ranges <- data.table(start=c(20,50,70), end=c(30,55,72))
dt[id %inrange% ranges]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This doesn't work for me, it does subset the dataframe but it looks to be near-random. I'm going to try my luck with rolling non-equi join, possibly from GenomicsRange